# Laravel Auth::attempt always return false?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Here is myscreen shot of database and my login input
[image]

```
public function action(Request $request){
         $username = $request->username;
         $pass = bcrypt($request->password);
         $credentials = [
                         'id' => $username,
                         'password' => $pass
                        ];

    dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));
         if (Auth::attempt(['id' => $username, 'password' => $pass])) {
            echo 'Ok';
         }else{
            echo 'Not ok';
         }
```

I'm trying to make a login action using laravel `auth::attempt`but it always return `false`.

Comment: Which fields are you using for login? Are you probably missing to add a `username` field to your table?

Comment: i'm using id and password for login. Should i use 'username' instead of 'id' ? @GerardReches

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use the `id` for authentication in your application, I would suggest to use `email` field for it, which Laravel uses by default.

Answer (score 3):

```
$pass = bcrypt($request->password);
```

should be

```
$pass = $request->password;
```

The `attempt` method will automatically handle the encryption and comparison. You are in effect bcrypting it twice, so a match isn't found